# Java not calculating properly distance from point to line

Tags: java, line, distance, point, trigonometry

as I say in title, im using a Java function to calculate that distance. The code below works ok and shows 0.0 distance:

```
  Point2D.Double p1 = new Point2D.Double(11, 8);
  Point2D.Double p2 = new Point2D.Double(8, 5);
  Line2D.Double r = new Line2D.Double(p1, p2);
  System.out.println(r.ptLineDist(9.56, 6.56));
```

But if I change this:

```
  Line2D.Double r = new Line2D.Double(p2, p1);
```

It shows 2.9802322387695312E-8 distance,  despite it is the same line.
¿Can somebody tells me if im right when I say this shouldn't happen?
¿What means 2.9802322387695312E-8? Thanks all.

Comment: 2.9802322387695312E-8 is [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). It means 2.9802322387695312 * 10^(-8), which is ~= 0.00000029802... which is a really small number. It would be really helpful if you could show us your distance calculation function, because probably some quirk in [float arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) is causing problems.

Comment: I didnt write the calculation function, just used Java API. Here is the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html#ptLineDist(double,%20double))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `Double` datatype, which uses floating point. In a nutshell, this representation has certain limitations, and not all numbers can be represented with perfect accuracy.

When you are computing the distance, you perform some operations on doubles, with possible intermediate values. When you change the order of `p1` and `p2`, you also change the order of operands. Because of the inability of `Doubles` to represent numbers precisely, properties such as associativity for addition don't hold entirely anymore. The two results that you get (0 and 2.9802322387695312E-8) have very close values, and illustrate what I mean by "approximate associativity".

Comment: Thank you, I guess I'm going to round that values.